# Realm has no setter or ivar for its bridge, which is not permitted

Tags: ios, react-native, jitsi-meet, realm-js

I want to use Jitsi-Meet (Video calling library) with Realm. When I run the app on iOS, Realm does not work. It shows the following error:

`2018-12-28 16:22:34.504 [error][tid:main][RCTModuleData.mm:179] Realm has no setter or ivar for its bridge, which is not permitted. You must either @synthesize the bridge property, or provide your own setter method.`

Realm works fine if I remove Jisti-Meet Library. And Jitsi-Meet works fine without realm as well.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Create a new react-native app: `react-native init AwesomeProject`
2. Install realm-js: `npm install realm --save` and `react-native link realm`
3. Install React Native Jisti Meet: `npm install react-native-jitsi-meet --save`
4. Under Build setting set **Dead Code Stripping** to No, set **Enable Bitcode** to No and **Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries** to Yes
5. add `node_modules/react-native-jitsi-meet/ios/WebRTC.framework` and `node_modules/react-native-jitsi-meet/ios/JitsiMeet.framework` to the Embed Binaries.
6. select `Build Settings`, find `Search Paths` . Edit BOTH `Framework Search Paths` and `Library Search Paths`. and  add path on BOTH sections with: `$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-jitsi-meet/ios` with `recursive`

Now run the app and the app will show the error.

### Code Sample

filename: App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import Realm from 'realm';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});


type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { realm: null };
  }


  componentWillMount() {
    Realm.open({
      schema: [{name: 'Dog', properties: {name: 'string'}}]
    }).then(realm => {
      realm.write(() => {
        realm.create('Dog', {name: 'Rex'});
      });
      this.setState({ realm });
    });
  }

  render() {

    const info = this.state.realm
    ? 'Number of dogs in this Realm: ' + this.state.realm.objects('Dog').length
    : 'Loading...';


    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
        <Button title="Video" 
        // onPress = {() => initiateVideoCall()} 
        />
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          {info}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

### Version of Realm and Tooling

- Realm JS SDK Version: 2.21.1 (Lower versions also have the same issue )
- Node or React Native: RN 0.57.8
- Client OS & Version: iOS Real Device - 12.1.2
- MacOS: 10.13.6 High Sierra
- Which debugger for React Native: None